# .NET Maui Load Image

Tags: c#, .net-maui

I'm trying to load an image in my code behind.  I can successfully load an image into an Image control using xaml, but in my xaml.cs file nothing appears.

Here is my xaml:

```
   <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="ImageView1"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Source="alpha.jpg" />
```

The image from "Resources/Images/alpha.jpg" is loaded. The Build Content is MauiImage.

But here is the code in the mainpage.xaml.cs file.

```
   ImageView1.Source = "CWON22.Resources.Images.beta.jpg";
```

The Image Control, ImageView1 is blank.

Comment: **When** is that cs code run?  Constructor? OnAppearing? By some user action such as button push? If in constructor, is it **after** InitializeComponent? If there is a `BindingContext = ...`, is it **before** that?

Comment: It is after everything is loaded in a ButtonClick event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```cs
ImageView1.Source = new ImageSource.FromResource("beta.jpg");

// OR
ImageView1.Source = new ImageSource.FromResource("Resources/Images/beta.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ImageView1.Source = new BitmapImage(
         new Uri(@CWON22.Resources.Images.beta.jpg, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
        );
```

Comment: Hashim, Can't find the using System.Windows.Media.Imaging assembly.
 for the BitmapImage

Comment: type:     using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
at the top of the class

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an embedded image, please set the `Build Action` to `Embedded resource`

And also refer to the following code:

```
ImageView1.Source =   ImageSource.FromResource("CWON22.Resources.Images.test.png");
```

For more information, check : [Load an embedded image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/image#load-an-embedded-image) .